# Customizing Editor Workbench by Adding Title Eclipse GMF

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-gmf

I want to add a title at the top of the canvas in my editor, that I generated using GMF in Eclipse. Can someone please direct me as to what changes I need to make to the generated code so as to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet for you that adds an SWT label at the top of Graphical Viewer for GEF's Logic Example editor. Yopu can easily do the same for the GMF editor because GMF's DiagramEditor has been created based on GEF's LogicEditor.

I have modified the following methods in GEF's LogicEditor:

```
private Composite graphicalControl;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor#createGraphicalViewer(org.eclipse
 * .swt.widgets.Composite)
 */
protected void createGraphicalViewer(Composite parent) {
    graphicalControl = new Composite(parent, SWT.None);
    graphicalControl.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Label label = new Label(graphicalControl, SWT.None);
    label.setText("MY DIAGRAM NAME!!!");
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));

    rulerComp = new RulerComposite(graphicalControl, SWT.NONE);
    super.createGraphicalViewer(rulerComp);
    rulerComp
            .setGraphicalViewer((ScrollingGraphicalViewer) getGraphicalViewer());
    rulerComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
}

protected Control getGraphicalControl() {
    return graphicalControl;
}
```

In addition to that change i removed the previous implementations of these methods in LogicEditor and replaced call to getGraphicalControl() with rulerComp for LogicEditor#configureGraphicalViewer() method (a the end there are 2 SWT listeners added)

Result on the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the title using SWT controls rather than GEF/GMF constructs.

Inside GEF's package org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts
Look at classes:
GraphicalEditor (no palette, just diagram viewer)
GraphicalEditorWithPalette (diagram viewer + palette with a help of SWT Splitter)
GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette (same as above with ability to hide the palette)

Note how palette is added to the editor. Something like that needs to be done to show the title.

My advice is subclass GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette, override #createPartControl(...) method to arrange diagram graphical viewer, palette viewer and title viewer. TitleViewer can be a subclass of DiagramGraphicalViewer that just displays one editpart - the diagram, the figure for which is being a label. Alternatively you can just use SWT Label instead of TitleViewer (which you'd need to create yourself). You'd have to provide model listening logic in this case to update the label's text for model changes if applicable.

Comment: GMF, GEF, JFace and Eclipse UI in general all depend on SWT. They are all mixed with SWT via MVC design pattern, where SWT control is a view. Draw2D is a view as well but Draw2D is a facade on top of SWT for painting figures on the canvas control. PaletteViewer is a controller with view being draw2d FigureCanvas (subclass of SWT Canvas), GraphicalViewer is a controller with view being FigureCanvas. Palette;s and Graphical viewers canvases are children of the Editor control which is SWT Composite.  #createPartControl(...) is responsible for placing palette and graphical viewer controls.

Comment: I'll try to provide you with a code snippet when i get a chance. See the implementation of GraphicalEditorWithPalette#createPartControl(Composite). This is the method where SWT controls for different editor parts such as palette and graphical (diagrm) viewers are put together on editor's widget - SWT Composite.